# Identifying error on the native app using appium when some field is blank

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

I am using appium to automate native android app UI and functionality. My requirement is to capture the error message that comes when the username is kept blank during login. The error message is shown with the red exclamation mark on username field and cannot be identified by uiautomator. Is there a way to capture the text of the error message via appium

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the element by using xpath and providing the text value you expect this error message Object to possess.

`$driver.find_element :xpath, '//text[@text="Err Msg"]'`

If element is found then you can retreive out other properties.

Comment: I would rather provoke the error, hardcode red text and search the element by text. Then retrieve it's xpath then for future use... but priya said that it's invisible for Appium. In this case nothing can be done, except taking the screenshot and storing it somewhere.